# C program using inotify to monitor multiple directories along with sub-directories?

Tags: linux, inotify

I have a program which monitors a directory (`/test`) and notifies me.
I want to improve this to monitor another directory (say /opt).
And also how to monitor it's subdirectories, currently I'll get notified of any changes were made to files under `/test`. But I'm not getting any notification if changes are made in a sub-directory of `/test`, for example:

```
touch /test/sub-dir/files.txt
```

Here's my current code - hope this will help

```
/*

Simple example for inotify in Linux.

inotify has 3 main functions.
inotify_init1 to initialize
inotify_add_watch to add monitor
then inotify_??_watch to rm monitor.you the what to replace with ??.
yes third one is  inotify_rm_watch()
*/


#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main(){
    int fd,wd,wd1,i=0,len=0;
    char pathname[100],buf[1024];
    struct inotify_event *event;

    fd=inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
    /* watch /test directory for any activity and report it back to me */
    wd=inotify_add_watch(fd,"/test",IN_ALL_EVENTS);

    while(1){
        //read 1024  bytes of events from fd into buf
        i=0;
        len=read(fd,buf,1024);
        while(i<len){
            event=(struct inotify_event *) &buf[i];


            /* check for changes */
            if(event->mask & IN_OPEN)
                printf("%s :was opened\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                printf("%s : modified\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_ATTRIB)
                printf("%s :meta data changed\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_ACCESS)
                printf("%s :was read\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
                printf("%s :file opened for writing was closed\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
                printf("%s :file opened not for writing was closed\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)
                printf("%s :deleted\n",event->name);

            if(event->mask & IN_DELETE)
                printf("%s :deleted\n",event->name);

            /* update index to start of next event */
            i+=sizeof(struct inotify_event)+event->len;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`inotify_add_watch` does not listen to changes in sub-directories. You have to detect when these sub-directories are created, and also `inotify_add_watch` them.

The most important thing to note is that after a sub-directory is created, you will be notified accordingly, but at the time you get that notification, files and sub-directories might already have been created inside that one, therefore you will "lose" these events, since you didn't get a chance to add a watch for the new sub-directory yet.

One way to avoid this problem is to scan the directory contents after you get the notification, so that you can see what's really in there. This creates an opportunity for adding further watches for them.

Answer (score 0):

In inotify, you need one watch per directory. For global notifications, there is fanotify or so.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to delete the subfolder and than recreate it every time you need to add something in it.